# ¿Como calcular o programar la media de una matriz con una calculadora Casio 35 +?

Tags: casio, basic

He navegado por la red y los foros para saber como calcular o hacer un programa para conocer la media de una matriz con una calculadora **Casio 35 +**  que utilice `Basic`.

Esto es lo que tengo por ahora:

```
Fill(1,Mat A) 'que ya fue creado con el tamaño correcto
Mat X*Mat A->Mat M
Mat X - Mat M->Mat Y 'seria mejor utilizar un Return ?
```

¿`Mat A`  ya fue creado con el tamaño correcto, pero conoces una manera de crearlo automaticamente en el programa? ¿Conoces un manera de obtener los vectores propios de la matriz `Y` ?

Comment: ¿Estás haciendo algún tipo de examen? :D

Comment: @AsierVillanueva si ! Y quiero utilisar la potencia de mi calculador para cansarme lo menos ;)